# xlwings: set cell formatting from python on a Mac specifically

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to format font size, font color, horizontal alignment, border style/weight etc on a worksheet using python `xlwings` on a Mac. I know you'd have to use the missing features to do this type of editing on python but i don't know what API member functions to use in order to do these formatting on Mac. The ones for windows I can find everywhere; for example:

```
import xlwings

wb = xlwings.Book('checker_output.xlsx')

wb.sheets.add('sheet1')

sht = wb.sheets['sheet1']

sht.range('A3:A26').api.Font.Size = 15
```

would work on the windows API, but not on a mac. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found you can use .api to center / left / right align but this is on a PC, perhaps it can work on Mac as well.

Set the value of the HorizontalAlignment property of the cell to:

- Center-aligned, we’d set HorizontalValue to -4108;
- Right-aligned, we’d set HorizontalValue to -4152;
- Left-aligned, we’d set HorizontalValue to -4131;

What it would look like:

```
import xlwings as xw
sht = xw.sheets.active
sht.range(f'$A1:$C5').api.HorizontalAlignment = -4131
```

Comment: this does not work on a Mac (xlwings v.0.25.2).